# How to use SASS to rewrite custom CSS methods from an external Vue module?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I'm using a third-party module in our Vue project called [`vue-cal`](https://github.com/antoniandre/vue-cal), which is for rendering a calendar. You can customise how your date cells look and such, using their [custom css](https://antoniandre.github.io/vue-cal/#css-notes) like this.

```css
<style>
.vuecal--month-view .vuecal__cell-content {justify-content: flex-start;}
.vuecal__cell.selected {background-color: red;}
</style>
```

However, we use sass for our project, and I tried rewriting it like below but now the `<style>` isn't being applied at all. How can I rewrite this in sass correctly, or is there no way to rewrite external libraries' custom methods like these in non-css syntax?

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.vuecal--month-view
  .vuecal__cell-content
    justify-content: flex-start 
.vuecal__cell.selected
  background-color: red
</style>
```

Sorry if this is a basic question - still a beginner to Vue, CSS and front-end in general.

**[EDIT]** Forgot to mention an important detail. We already use `sass-loader@7.1.0`, and I've already written some other code in `sass` for other components. Those are being rendered fine. That's why I'm wondering if it has to do with `vue-cal`-specific methods.

Comment: Given the simplicity of the style rules, is there any reason why you must use Sass?

Comment: might be specificity issue, scoped CSS might be overriding your CSS generated from sass

Comment: @Phil This is a team project and we're using sass for our other components - so for consistency's sake, I'd like to use sass for this component too if possible.

Comment: So does the CSS version actually work and the Sass version not? What does your browser's _Elements_ console say about the styles applied to the relevant elements?

Comment: @Phil You're right, the css version works and sass doesn't.

Comment: Can't see how I'm _"right"_ since I just asked the question but can you please address the latter part of my comment?

Comment: @Phil Sorry, accidentally added the comment while I was still typing. I don't see anything on the Styles console regarding the two items that I changed (position of cell content and background color of selected cell). There are no errors in the console in either case, regardless of whether it's css or sass. It's just that the style isn't applied if I use the code block above written in sass.

Comment: What `sass` package are you using? `sass` (aka `dart-sass`), `node-sass`, something else? What version?

Comment: Adding a newline didn't change anything. Like I asked originally, is it possible that some library-specific css methods don't allow rewriting in sass? As for the package, we're using `node-sass@4.12.0`.

Comment: And you have other `<style lang="sass">` blocks that do work correctly?

Comment: I do, in the other components in our project.

Comment: Definitely using `lang="sass"` and not `lang="scss"`? (sorry for all the questions, this all looks like it should work)

Comment: No worries, thank you for trying to pinpoint the issues. Yes, the code in my example is a letter-for-letter copy of my actual code. No way it's `"scss"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

It turned out that the problem was not `sass`, but the fact that the style was `scoped`. `Scoped` styles are only applied to the component itself, but `vue-cal` is an external module so the styles weren't applied. Removing `scoped` immediately fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use vue-loader to pre-process the SASS into native CSS

Step 1:

```
npm install -D sass-loader sass
```

Step 2, in your webpack config file, make sure to have:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted

      // this will apply to both plain `.scss` files
      // AND `<style lang="scss">` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  // plugin omitted
}
```

This is the barebones needed. For further information see:
[vue-loader documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass-vs-scss)

Comment: Pretty sure the preference these days is for `sass` (dart) instead of `node-sass` ~ https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention an important detail. We already use `sass-loader@7.1.0`, and I've written some other stuff in `sass` and it's been fine. That's why I'm wondering if it has to do with `vue-cal`-specific methods.

Comment: did you import the css to your component? and does the loader compile the css correctly then?

Comment: @Dor-Ron Correct, if I write the `<style>` in css it's rendered, but not if I use the sass version. So I'm wondering if my sass syntax is wrong, or if this code has to be written in css.

Comment: if you view source for the sass version does the styles you want appear? if not then the sass is not being compiled and injected correctly, otherwise im unsure

Comment: Do you mean this line when I inspect the page source? If so, they're the same for both the css and sass versions. `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-[long-string].css?body=1" />`

Comment: @Risa open that file and find out if your CSS rules are in there

Comment: @Phil It's completely blank for both css/sass. Also blank for other pages that use scoped sass. But I definitely know that the styles are being applied -  the page turns out differently if I delete those style lines.